# C++ Error C2061

Tags: colors, c++-cli, rgb, argb

I was trying to set the BackColor of my form in C++, and I a syntax error, to do with the 'FromArgb' statement, when using the code:

```
this->BackColor = gcnew Color::FromArgb(0,0,15);
```

What should I do?

Comment: C++ has no notion of colors. You should provide more context about which framework or library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us enough context to answer, but I'll hazard a guess that `FromArgb` is a function, not a type, in which case it doesn't make sense to `new` (or `gcnew`) it.

If that's the case, and assuming `BackColor` is a `Color` object and not a pointer, and that `FromArgb` returns a `Color` by value, then you want

```
this->BackColor = Color::FromArgb(0,0,15);
```

If that doesn't work, please let us know exactly what `BackColor` and `FromArgb` are.

Answer (score 0):

Color is a public value class Color - hence gcnew is wrong.
Also the number of arguments do not match:

```
public: static Color FromArgb(
    unsigned char a, 
    unsigned char r, 
    unsigned char g, 
    unsigned char b)
```